# How can I prevent prettier from changing single quotes to doubles?

Tags: eslint, quotes, prettier

If I have a string like this: `'don\'t fix me'` prettier will change single quotes to douples: `"don't fix me"`. This is extremely frustrating since our .eslint rules will give errors and I have to manually fix every single string back to `'don\'t fix me'` format before I can push to our repository. I can't change prettier or eslint rules as they are managed by seniors. Is there any way to fix this behaviour without messing with `.eslintrc` or `.prettierrc`?

I am using VS Code, but haven't found extension to help me here.